# Why this bash construct works? (parameter-substitution)

Tags: bash

Code:
`${non_existent_variable:+whatever} && echo "it works"`

Result is `it works`. But why? part before && evaluates to empty string. Trying to run however: `&& echo test` gives an error.

I've got this by accident trying to create ternary operator replacement for bash with different results for set and unset variable. It works this way, but I'm lost why it works at all.

`PARAM=$(${tested_variable:+false} && echo var_exists || echo var_empty)`

Comment: @jeanrjc: but `"" && echo test` gives `: command not found`, however `$(echo "") && echo test` works

Comment: It looks like unquoted, empty variable expansion return 0 in all common shells `for sh in sh bash ksh zsh; do $sh -c '${nonexistent} && echo yes' ; done`. Couldn't find the spec for this behavior, though.

Comment: I would only read the contrary behavior (`${empty_var}` being syntactically equivalent to a completely null string with no tokens/words -- meaning a no-word "null string" as distinguished from something that tokenizes as a word containing an empty string, ie. `''`) as intuitive only if `$foo` and `eval "$foo"` were identical, which they **emphatically** are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [section 2.9.1 of the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01):

> A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.

The very last sentence of section 2.9.1 is the relavant one:

> If there is a command name, execution shall continue as described in Command Search and Execution . If there is no command name, but the command contained a command substitution, the command shall complete with the exit status of the last command substitution performed. **Otherwise, the command shall complete with a zero exit status.**

So if after all expansion, redirections, etc, no command name is found, it is treated as completing successfully with an exit status of 0.

However, the *grammar* does not allow a null string prior to the `&&` operator. The following is a *syntax* error:

```
&& echo it works
```

The only way to get a completely empty simple command is to have a non-empty string "evaporate" during expansion. One way of accomplishing that is with the *unquoted* parameter expansion that produces the empty string, which is exactly what `${non_existent_variable:+whatever}` does.

Comment: thank you - it makes sense. For everybody else thank you for valuable discussion/info

Comment: just another check: `$non_existent_variable && echo test` also works, so it seems that it's perfectly valid shell script and not a weird hack as I was at first thinking that it is. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The resulting string is not important, [what the `&&` construct is testing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) is the *exit code* of the statement before it (i.e. `$?`) and not what's echoed on screen. Because there wasn't an error in the parameter expansion (indeed, I'm not sure there could be an error) the statement continues.

In comments you asked why `$(echo "") && echo test` echoes a value, and it's the same reason. The `echo` statement exits `0` (i.e. `true`) so the subshell exits `0` as well, and the statement continues running.

Comment: Exit status and return value are synonymous in shell, and are separate from standard output.

Comment: Also, `$(echo "")` behaves the same way `${not_a_variable}`  would; both produce unquoted empty strings that the shell discards, not an empty string that is kept as a word.

Comment: (I did take back the downvote, but your answer doesn't correctly explain *why* the expression before the `&&` produces a 0 exit status.)

Comment: @chepner, ...how does this claim that the subshell's output generates a word when parsed? I'm having trouble seeing where the error in its explanation is.

Comment: It doesn't; the comment asked why an error results from `"" && echo it works` , which is not the same thing.

Comment: I was only answering the part of the comment that said, "however `$(echo "") && echo test` works."

Answer (score 1):

```
${non_existent_variable:+whatever} && echo "it works"
```

Works (prints "it works) because<sup>[1]</sup> this is an `AND and OR lists`:

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by the && and || control operators, respectively. AND and OR lists are executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
>          command1 && command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.

That is: anything as `command1` that has an exit value of true will trigger the execution of the `command2` after the `&&`.

It is exactly the same kind of code as this:

```
true && echo "it works"
```

Which also is equivalent to this:

```
: && echo "it works"
```

And also **works the same as** (even if the variable is unset):

```
$ a=''
$ $a && echo "it works"
```

Yes, the variable expands to a `null string`, but its exit status is zero:
From `man bash`:

> SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION
>
> If there is a command name left after expansion, execution proceeds as described below. **Otherwise**, the command exits. If one of the expansions contained a command substitution, the exit status of the command is the exit status of the last command substitution performed. **If there were no command substitutions, the command exits with a status of zero**.

You can see the exit status with:

```
$ a=''
$ $a; echo "$?"
0
```

Even if there is a setting to `false` before:

```
$ false; $a; echo "$?"
0
```

Also note that `"$a"` will not work (and also will fail in all shells I tested):

```
$ "$a"
bash: : command not found
```

<sup>[1]</sup> Answered with bash syntax as this question was tagged bash. But what was explained above works in all shells I tested.